# Are Android apps able to communicate with desktop application over USB?

Tags: android, usb, desktop

I want to write an Android app that communicates with a Windows desktop application over USB. Is that possible?

I found a lot of conflicting information, maybe because some answers were from late 2010 or 2011. What is the current state?

There must be no rooting of the device.

If possible, could you point me to sources?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a similar question on SO. You might want to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021732/software-based-android-accessory-on-windows) He refers to a project that works on Linux and is trying to port it to Windows. So generally it is possible to to this.